# Registering AIR application for launching at startup

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I was going through this tutorial at adobe:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/startup_options.html

I downloaded the installer, and ticked the launch at startup option. But it does not work at my side. I am using Mac. Any clues, what additionally need to be done to have a startup launch option in an AIR application.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if your platform supports startup option by simply using:

```
    if (NativeApplication.supportsStartAtLogin){
        trace("I SUPPORT START AT LOGIN");
        //NativeApplication.nativeApplication.startAtLogin = true;
    } else {
        trace("I DONT SUPPORT");
    }
```

I used it several times on Windows based computers, and this works quite well, not sure about MAC though.